# Migrating a single 2010 site collection to 2013 site collection

Tags: 2013, 2010, migration

I have a fresh 2013 TEST and PROD SharePoint farm. At this point, I am just trying to migrate a SP 2010 Sales site collection to 2013 site collection. What are the steps for this. I did a backup of the source db and restored it to 2013 db. Is spmount be the next step.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a site collection in SharePoint 2013, detach the newly created content database and then attach the 2010 content database to the site collection. SharePoint 2013 will upgrade it for you.

The process is explained here http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/cory-granata/how-to-upgrade-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013-using-database-attach/

Comment: Arsalan: that process did not work. Could it be the new sp 2013 farm is based on completely different services accounts including the domain. Do I need to add the service accounts to the 2010 content db before taking a back up and restore. Also SP roles for DB are missing after restoring 2010 db to 2013 db.

Comment: Hi Arsalan, the backup > restore to blank DB > spmount = did not work. Could it be the farm is on another domain and I need to add all the service accounts before I take sp 2010 backup thru sql mgmt. Also I don't see spdataaccess and spreadonly role after migrating to 2013 db.